# Showing the Metric Function Satisfies the Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, metric-spaces

Let $d(X,Y)=E\left[ \frac{|X-Y|}{1+|X-Y|}\right]$. How can we show
$$d(X,Z)\leq d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)?$$

Comment: What do you know about linearity of expectation?

Comment: Why did this flat PSQ receive two upvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically only need two things here:

- the first as Eric points out is the linearity of the expectation
- the second is the easy to verify inequality $\frac{\lvert a+b\rvert}{1+\lvert a+b\rvert}\leq \frac{ \lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert}{1+\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert} $ (you can verify this by cross multiplying and using the fact, that the absolute value is a norm)

After this, it is essentially just plugging in. We get for real valued random variables $X,Y,Z$:

$$
d(X,Z)=E\left[ \frac{\lvert X-Z+Y-Y\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Z+Y-Y\rvert} \right]=E\left[ \frac{\lvert X-Y+Y-Z\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Y+Y-Z\rvert} \right]
$$
Now use the facts from the above two points and that $\lvert\cdot\rvert\geq0$ (important for the upcoming denomintor), we eventually get 
\begin{align}
E\left[ \frac{\lvert X-Y+Y-Z\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Y+Y-Z\rvert} \right]&\leq E\left[ \frac{\lvert X-Y\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Y\rvert+\lvert Y-Z\rvert} \right]+E\left[ \frac{\lvert Y-Z\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Y\rvert+\lvert Y-Z\rvert} \right]\\
&\leq E\left[ \frac{\lvert X-Y\rvert}{1+\lvert X-Y\rvert} \right]+E\left[ \frac{\lvert Y-Z\rvert}{1+\lvert Y-Z\rvert} \right]=d(X,Y)+d(Y,Z)
\end{align}

Comment: I think you'd better mention something about the "monotonicity" of the expectation operator. In other words, if $X \leq Y$ in the sense that $X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in P$, then $E[X] \leq E[Y]$. Even though it seems fairly straightforward, but the validity of your answer depends on it.

Comment: @user6547573 true, I used this implicitly....there are also some other details missing like for example whether or not the expectation actually exists.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly the other missing detail that is usually overlooked in most solutions.

Comment: @stressed-out anyway, thanks for pointing out. I'll leave the answer as it is. Together with the comments the answer outlines everything one needs.